# Error while running JsTestDriver

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, js-test-driver

JsTestDriver is throwing this error

```
line 63:35 mismatched input 'with' expecting Identifier
line 63:82 missing RPAREN at ';'
```

I'm running this command

```
java -jar jsTestDriver/JsTestDriver-1.3.4.b.jar --config jsTestDriver/jsTestDriver.conf --testOutput target/ --tests all
```

or

```
xvfb-run java -jar jsTestDriver/JsTestDriver-1.3.4.b.jar --config jsTestDriver/jsTestDriver.conf --testOutput target/ --tests all --browser firefox
```

i get the below output when i run the above command

```
setting runnermode QUIET
line 63:35 mismatched input 'with' expecting Identifier
line 63:82 missing RPAREN at ';'
Firefox: Reset
Firefox: Reset
```

is it just a warning or error?? What should i do to fix it??